# How to remove brackets from string in php?

Tags: php, string, preg-replace, str-replace

I have the following string and would like to use str_replace or preg_replace to remove the brackets but am unsure how. I have been able to remove the opening brackets using str_replace but can't remove the closing brackets.

This is the sting:

```
$coords = '(51.50972493425563, -0.1323877295303646)';
```

I have tried:

```
<?php echo str_replace('(','',$coords); ?>
```

which removed the opening brackets but am now under the impression that I need preg_replace to remove both.

How does one go about this?

Help appreciated

Answer (score 69, accepted):

Try with:

```
str_replace(array( '(', ')' ), '', $coords);
```

Comment: Just a note that this might have unintended consequences. For example, when $coords = "(testing (it) out)" the result is "testing it out" instead of "testing (it) out"; A safer way would probably be to use trim() as suggested by Sarfraz. The str_replace works for this example only because there are not multiple parentheses.

Answer (score 51):

If brackets always come on beginging and end, you can use [`trim`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.trim.php) easily:

```
$coords = trim($coords, '()');
```

Result:

```
51.50972493425563, -0.1323877295303646
```

Comment: This is remove only ) brackets.

Answer (score 2):

```
echo str_replace(
     array('(',')'), array('',''), 
     $coords);
```

or just do str_replace twice....

```
echo str_replace(')', '', str_replace('(','',$coords));
```

Answer (score 1):

i think you need to write your coords here as a string else you get syntax error ;). Anyway, this is the solution i think.

```
$coords = "(51.50972493425563, -0.1323877295303646)";

$aReplace = array('(', ')');
$coordsReplaced = str_replace($aReplace , '', $coords);
```

Greets,
Stefan

Answer (score 0):

it is easier than you think, str_replace can have an array as first parameter

```
 <?php echo str_replace(array('(',')'),'',$coords); ?>
```